# Ошибочная информация о вступлении модераторов в должность

Tags: дефект, выборы, даты

В [списке модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) ошибочно указана информация о вступлении модераторов в должность.
По крайней мере для Grundy и Barmaley:

> [image: Назначен]

Они [были выбраны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4), а не назначены. В случае с Barmaley может иметь место предыстория (уже был ранее модератором, потом терял этот статус). Но вот Grundy, насколько я знаю, ромб получал только однажды на [выборах #4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4).

Comment: (¬‿¬)(¬‿¬)(¬‿¬)

Comment: Неужели @Grundy на самом деле не выбран, а результаты подтасованы?!

Comment: Это все из-за электронного голосования.